# How to invert a ranking data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ranking

How can I invert this data.frame:

```
df = data.frame(A = c(1, 3, 2, NA, NA),
                B = c(1, 4, 3, 2, NA),
                C = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 2))
```

to obtain the following inverted data frame:

```
df.inv = data.frame(A = c(3, 1, 2, NA, NA),
                    B = c(4, 1, 2, 3, NA),
                    C = c(5, 3, 2, 1, 4))
```

Is there a simple way to do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am stealing the `rank()` approach from @akrun, but with less "tidy":

```
list2DF(lapply(-df, rank, na.last="keep"))

    A  B C
 1  3  4 5
 2  1  1 3
 3  2  2 2
 4 NA  3 1
 5 NA NA 4
```

Answer (score 3):

We may loop `across` the columns apply `rank` on the inverted signed values

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ rank(-.x, na.last = "keep")))
```

-output

```
   A  B C
1  3  4 5
2  1  1 3
3  2  2 2
4 NA  3 1
5 NA NA 4
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I learned about `na.last = "keep"` from you. I wonder why `order()` doesn't have that option, would be quite useful.